# Magento Product Images upload not working in my code

Tags: magento-1.7, php, csv

I have below code which should update product images in Magento using product sku from csv file.
In my csv file, there are two columns, First column in Product SKU and second with Image Name.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    //Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); 
    define('CSV_PATH','csvfiles/');

    $csv_fileoutput = CSV_PATH . "output_imagesupload.csv";
    $csvfileoutput = fopen($csv_fileoutput, 'a');

    $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product/incoming/';
    $file_handle = fopen("csvfiles/images_insert.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $productSKU = $line_of_text[0];
        $productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($productSKU);
        if ($productid) 
        {
            $Products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
            $fileName = $line_of_text[1];
            $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;

            if(file_exists($filePath)) {

                $Products->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
                $Products->save();


            /*  $Products->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath,'image',true,false);
                $Products->save();
*/
    /*  
                $setbaseimage=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($objProduct);
                $setbaseimage->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath,array('image','small_image','thumbnail'),true,false);
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                $setbaseimage->save();
    */
            } else{
                echo $productSKU . " Not done \n";

            }
                $my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid); 
                $url = $my_product->getProductUrl();

                fputcsv($csvfileoutput, array($productSKU,$url));   
        }
        else {echo $productSKU." - Product is not available\n"; }

    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    ?>
```

Below is my csv file data -

```
WPL8573228  8573239-WPL-N-8.jpg
WPL8573229  8573240-WPL-N-8.jpg
WPL8573230  8573241-WPL-N-8.jpg
WPL8573239  8573242-WPL-N-8.jpg
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error. But Images are not assigning to that product. I have uploaded images on `/media/catalog/product/incoming` directory and in csv file image name is added.

Comment: Did you checked `$filePath` showing right path of the file? right now I am not able to run your code so

Comment: Yes that was error .. But after echo and changing path it still not uploading images

Comment: I am not sure, but you are facing problem in file path, image name etc.. debug them step by step by printing filepath and file name.

Comment: Why you are commented product save() functions?

Comment: I tried different function to update images. Those are not working.

Comment: can you add csv file data in qus?

Comment: @Abdul Please check updated question. Csv Data Added.

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps:

**Step : 1**
Upload your csv file with file name `products.csv` in `var` folder and file data is

```
----------------------------------
Product SKU Image Name
----------------------------------
WPL8573228  8573239-WPL-N-8.jpg
----------------------------------
WPL8573229  8573240-WPL-N-8.jpg
----------------------------------
WPL8573230  8573241-WPL-N-8.jpg
----------------------------------
WPL8573239  8573242-WPL-N-8.jpg
```

---

**Step : 2**
Add your images in folder `media\catalog\product\incoming`.

**Step : 3** Create **sample.php** file at magento root folder and add bellow code in file

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class ABDUL
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $filePath = 'var/products.csv';
        $csvObject = new Varien_File_Csv();
        $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product/incoming/';
        try {
            $productsData = $csvObject->getData($filePath);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($productsData as $productData) {
                if($count > 0) {
                    $sku        = $productData[0];
                    $imageName  = $productData[1];
                    $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku, null, 'sku');  
                    if($product->getId()) {
                        $imagePath = $importDir.$imageName;
                        if(file_exists($imagePath)) {
                            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), true, false);
                            $product->save();
                            echo "{$sku} - Product image has been added.</br>";
                        }
                    }else {
                       echo "{$sku} - Product is not available</br>";
                    }

                }
                $count++;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$obj = new ABDUL();
$obj->index();
?>
```

**Step : 4** Run `sample.php` file in your browser and after check those products.

Comment: No its not working. It hangs my system and terminal.

Comment: It would be better if you provide solution on my code..